# How to Center Floated Divs in a Container

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to center floated divs in a container and if so how?

For example I have a page with a container div containing lots of variable sized (dynamically generated) floated (left) divs. The divs overflow onto the next line reguarly but they are never centered in the container div, instead alined with the left. It looks like this:

```
----------------------------
-                          -
- +++  +++++  ++++  ++     -
- +++  +++++  ++++  ++     -
-                          -
- ++   ++++++  +++  +      -
- ++   ++++++  +++  +      -
-                          -
----------------------------
```

Whereas I would like the floated divs centered in the container like this:

```
----------------------------
-                          -
-   +++  +++++  ++++  ++   -
-   +++  +++++  ++++  ++   -
-                          -
-   ++   ++++++  +++  +    -
-   ++   ++++++  +++  +    -
-                          -
----------------------------
```

Thanks,

DLiKS

Comment: Did you search at all for this question?

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269245/centering-floating-divs-within-another-div

Comment: I answered this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22218210/703717)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is possible. Using http://www.pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm and http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Centering_Block_Element as a source.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the concept, using the HTML and CSS from below: https://jsfiddle.net/t9qw8m5x/

```
<div id="outer">
    <ul id="inner">
        <li><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Button 2 with long text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Button 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the minimum CSS needed for the effect:

```
#outer {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}

#inner {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%; 
}

#inner > li {
    float: left;
}
```

Explanation:

Start off with just the `li { float: left; }` rule. Then wrap those floats in the `left: 50%; relative position`, so the left edge of the `<ul>`'s box is in the horizontal centre of the page, then use the rules in `#outer` to correctly adjust it so the centre of `#inner` is aligned with the page.

Comment: The nature of links is they become obsolete, so please provide at least a direction in your reply, without relying on the links.

Comment: Both examples fail, if the floats break line. 2nd artikle has obsolete links.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the total amount of screen space width that the desired layout will occupy then make the parent the same width and apply margin:auto.

```css
.outer {
  /* floats + margins + borders = 270 */
  max-width: 270px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.myFloat {
    /* 3 floats x 50px = 150px */
    width: 50px;
    /* 6 margins x 10px = 60px */
    margin: 10px;
    /* 6 borders x 10px = 60px */
    border: 10px solid #6B6B6B;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="myFloat">Float 1</div>
  <div class="myFloat">Float 2</div>
  <div class="myFloat">Float 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS3 you can also achieve this with flexbox:

HTML:

```
<ul id="flexcontainer">
     <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 2 with long text</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Min CSS:

```
#flex-container {
    display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

#flex-container > li {
    float: left;
}
```

Fiddle (with some styling for visualisation): https://jsfiddle.net/k5o37dff/4/

More about flexbox: https://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

Browser support: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Answer (score 0):

just beginner

```css
.container{
width:80% ;height:100px ; border: solid 3px goldenrod; display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; 
float: right; position: relative; right: 10%; }

.white{width:50%;height:50% ; background-color: honeydew;}

.blue{ width:50%;height:50%; background-color: indigo;}
```

```html
<!--display flex & flex-wrap properties & chess board -->


  <div class="container" >
    <div class="white"></div> <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>  <div class="white"></div> 
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Is this an answer, a new question, or...? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -6):

A nice trick to center "div" element is to set "margin: auto", it will center them.

Comment: the width must be know and set

Answer (score -6):

```
<div id='contain'><center><div id='content'>qwerty</div></center></div>
```

**OR**

```
<div id='contain'><div id='content'>qwerty</div></div>

<style type='text/css'>

#content   {

  width:200px;

  height:200px;

  margin:auto;
  /* margin:auto; requires width and i think height to be defined in nearly all browsers */

  }</style>
```