# How to horizontally center two divs within a header div?

Tags: html, css, center

I have a header div that is fixed to the top of the browser window at 100% width. Within the header div there is a div with title text and there is a div with a horizontal list. The horizontal list div should appear to the right of the title text div.

Here is my CSS and HTML:

```css
#header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#333333;
  padding:20px;
}

#title {
  float:left;
  color:#000000;
  font-size:30px;
  margin-right:24px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  padding:8px;
}

#navigation ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none;
}

#navigation ul li {
  display:inline;
  margin-right:20px;
  padding:3px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}

#navigation ul li a {
  color:#000000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title">Some Title Text</div>
  <div id="navigation"><ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul></div>
</div>
```

So right now the title and navigation divs are left aligned inside the header div. How can I horizontally center the title and navigation divs?

**Edit:** Would prefer a solution that doesn't use a hardcoded width(eg. `width: 500px`) since the list size isn't always the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering floating divs within another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269245/centering-floating-divs-within-another-div)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method that works with changing widths of the header and/ or of the two divs (if the title gets longer or shorter or if navigation items are added or removed):

Set `text-align: center` on the `#header`, and `display: inline-block` on `#title` and `#navigation` - demo http://dabblet.com/gist/3151355

Changes in CSS:

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:#333333;
    padding:20px;
    text-align: center; /* added */
}
#title {
    color:#000000;
    font-size:30px;
    margin-right:24px;
    display: inline-block; /* took out float:left and added this */
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding:8px;
}
#navigation {
    display: inline-block; /* added */
}
```

I've also added `#navigation ul li:last-child {margin-right:0}` in order not to have `24px` margin after the last list item (which would make it seem like there is more space on the right side of the navigation)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the title and navigation divs in another div, and then center that div using `margin: 0 auto`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="center">
        <div id="title">Some Title Text</div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
#center {
    width: 500px; /* or any other width */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rJyuJ/

Comment: This won't work if you want to change the width of the menu, or have it dynamically resize.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution because the number of list items isn't always the same. For example if the user is logged in then there might be more items. Is there a way to do it without having to specify `width: 500px`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269245/centering-floating-divs-within-another-div

Answer (score 0):

hi could you please try with following css for #header

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:#333333;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```