# Aligning 4 DIVs to the center of a page

Tags: html, css

I've a page of content with 4 div's side by side.

At the moment the divs are sticking to the left.

I've tried to wrap the div's in a container and text-align that center, but it won't work.

here is the code i'm using i've remove some image URL's etc

```css
#downloads {
  text-align: center!important;
}

.dl-buttons {
  text-align: center!important;
}

- I know this is duplicate but was testing .windows a {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="downloads">
  <div class="row dl-buttons">
    <div class="col-3 col-6-sx windows">
      <a class="bt1" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-6-sx mac">
      <a class="bt1" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-6-sx android">
      <a class="bt1" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-6-sx ios">
      <a class="bt1" href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- all other classes / mac / android / ios are the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center two divs within a header div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582226/how-to-horizontally-center-two-divs-within-a-header-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.dl-buttons{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.dl-buttons > div {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block for the `col-3` elements. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/jcybgsw4/)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a small working code for you.

```css
.dl-buttons {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.dl-buttons>div {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="downloads">
  <div class="row dl-buttons">
    <div class="col-3 col-6-sx windows">
      <a class="bt1" href="#">s</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-6-sx mac">
      <a class="bt1" href="#">a</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-6-sx android">
      <a class="bt1" href="#">f</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-6-sx ios">
      <a class="bt1" href="#">e</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```