# Center <div> inside a <div>

Tags: html, css

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/z4udfg3o/

I want the divs "caixa" to be centered in the div "produtos". I was able to do it with exact values using `margin-left`. But I want it to be responsive for other screen sizes so I putted `margin-left` and `margin-right` as `auto`.

Image of desired format:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering floating divs within another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269245/centering-floating-divs-within-another-div)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: Trying to center an element that is 100% wide doesn’t make much sense. Yes, via the auto margins it _is_ centered. But because there is no space left on either side, you don’t _see_ much effect of it.

Comment: @VirgildeMeijer, no as he id centering multiple divs.

Comment: @JordiNebot, doesn't seem to contain answer with equal spacing including first and last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
.produtos {
    width: 100%;
    background: gray;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.caixa {
    width: 27.1%;
    height: 250px;
    background: darksalmon;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
section {
  padding: 2em 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: antiquewhite;
}

section:before, section:after {
  content: "";
}

div {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize your answer. Only stating the support for others. I think a rate of 2,5% unsupported global browsers is noteworthy.

Answer (score 0):

Like This?

```css
.produtos {
  width: 100%;
  height: 252px;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
.caixa {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: darksalmon;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="produtos">
  <div class="caixa">
    <img src="imagens/croa.png" style="margin-left:60px;">
    <p style="text-align:center;">Temos os melhores produtos do mercado! Nossos competidores ajoelham-se perante a nossa qualidade!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="caixa">
    <img src="imagens/dinheiro.png" style="margin-left:60px;">
    <p style="text-align:center;">Preços mais baratos do mercado! Promoções 24/7! Se houver ofertas mais baratas diga e fazemos promoção de 0.01€!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="caixa">
    <img href="#" src="imagens/definicoes.png" style="margin-left:60px;">
    <p style="text-align:center;">Nosso departamento de apoio ao cliente está ativo 24/7! Resolveremos todas as suas dúvidas!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, i suggest you to have a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like below:

```css
#wrap {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 4px; 
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;  
}

#one, #two, #three {
     background: #ccc;
     display: inline-block;    
     padding: 20px;
     width:20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one">I am div 1</div>
    <div id="two">I am div 2</div>
    <div id="three">I am div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your css like below

```
.produtos
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 252px;
        background: gray;
        text-align: center;
    }

.caixa
    {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        background: darksalmon;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        display: inline-block; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code sets the orange boxes as `display: inline-block` which causes them to follow the text flow, which is set to `center` in the parent container. This allows the boxes to flow depending on available screen space. On wide screens they're all side by side, on smaller ones they're arranged vertically.

I have also modified the HTML in order to get rid of newlines between the boxes. These newlines would cause margins otherwise.

```css
.produtos
    {
        width: 100%;
        background: gray;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
.caixa
    {
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        background: darksalmon;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="produtos">
        <div class="caixa"> 
            <img src="imagens/croa.png" style="margin-left:60px;">
            <p style="text-align:center;">Temos os melhores produtos do mercado! Nossos competidores ajoelham-se perante a nossa qualidade!</p>
        </div
        ><div class="caixa">
            <img src="imagens/dinheiro.png" style="margin-left:60px;">
            <p style="text-align:center;">Preços mais baratos do mercado! Promoções 24/7! Se houver ofertas mais baratas diga e fazemos promoção de 0.01€!</p>
        </div
        ><div class="caixa">
            <img href="#" src="imagens/definicoes.png" style="margin-left:60px;">
            <p style="text-align:center;">Nosso departamento de apoio ao cliente está ativo 24/7! Resolveremos todas as suas dúvidas!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should balance the width of both divs. "caixa" and  "produtos".
I think using `%` will be responsive for other screeen size too.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4udfg3o/3/)

Hope Fiddle link help you .

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways, but if the boxes are to contain an image or something, then you will need a fixed aspect ratio, that can be accomplished like this:

```css
.wrapper{float:left; width:100%; background-color:deeppink;}
.lil-box{float:left; width:22%; margin:0 5.665%; background-color:bisque;}
.tight-fit{float:left; width:100%; margin-top:100%;}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="lil-box">
            <div class="tight-fit"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="lil-box">
            <div class="tight-fit"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="lil-box">
            <div class="tight-fit"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works for you. I added each div class `row` for each to so you can set the padding in class*emphasized text* `row`.

```css
.produtos
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 252px;
        }
    
.caixa
    {
        width: 33%;
        height: 100%;
        background: darksalmon;
        border:1px solid red;
        float: left; 
    }
  .row{
        height:100%;
        padding:0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="produtos">
        <div class="caixa"> 
        <div class="row">
            <img src="imagens/croa.png">
            <p style="text-align:center;">Temos os melhores produtos do mercado! Nossos competidores ajoelham-se perante a nossa qualidade!</p>
        </div>
          </div>
        <div class="caixa">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="imagens/dinheiro.png">
            <p style="text-align:center;">Preços mais baratos do mercado! Promoções 24/7! Se houver ofertas mais baratas diga e fazemos promoção de 0.01€!</p>
        </div> </div>
        <div class="caixa">
          <div class="row">
            <img href="#" src="imagens/definicoes.png">
            <p style="text-align:center;">Nosso departamento de apoio ao cliente está ativo 24/7! Resolveremos todas as suas dúvidas!</p>
        </div> </div>
    </div>
```